# How to display perl output in html format without using any perl modules like CGI, etc

Tags: html, perl

I have a perl script, output of this script to be redirected to an html page. But the limitation is, I cannot use anything like CGI module, TextToHTML, PrettyPrinter, etc. I have to work without any such features.

Output to be displayed in table (.html)format:

```
 ____________________________________________________ 
|Table Name   |   Changes Found   |   Action         |
|-------------|-------------------|------------------|
|table1       | Record 0 differs  | Data Type should |
|             | in content        | be changed.      |
|             |                   |                  |
|table2       |      ...          |      ...         |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you're a beginner that should be a good exercise, and if not where is the problem?

Comment: boss is boss, have to listen them @mpapec

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. You have described your task. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Use print statements to generate your HTML. Seriously though, you must be able to use modules, CGI is a core and has been for a very long time.

Comment: Thanku for help. I will try to do that way. @Dr.Avalanche

Comment: But isn't it about fifteen years since everyone worked out that using CGI's HTML generation methods was a terrible idea? Use a templating system instead.

Comment: @DaveCross True, but if CGI.pm, which is core, is out of the question I suspect that using a templating module or a modern web framework is likely also out of the question. If only people would resolve non technical issues (boss says no modules) before trying to solve problems ;) Cheers